# Charging li-ion cell using constant-voltage

Tags: lithium-ion, charging

I need the li-ion battery for power failure backup on an old phone used as a sip-phone.  The battery needs to keep it running less than 15 minutes so far from full is OK.  The old battery with constant plugged in charger did not last, suddenly it became thicker.

I have an old charger with a max voltage of 4.5V, with a diode in series the voltage stabilize at 3.88V.  How will the cell cope with that constant voltage for let us say 5 years. I guess the real need for the battery as supply will be maximum 4 times a year, and always less then 15 minutes.  I tried from a fully charged battery and that kept it running for more than 3 days.

A regular charging circuit like whats built in to the cellphone battery has the goal to keep the battery fully charged so you may use the phone for hours or days between charging, my goal is to have a unit with battery backup witch I may leave for years without maintenance.  The battery backup does not have to last for a long time without power.  Maybe I just should go for a huge battery of electrolytic capacitors with a voltage limit of at least 8V, and keep it charged at 4V.  That capacitor bank will have need loots of room compared with e.g. an 18650 cell. I am not sure the tp4056 will be OK for such use. Do you think so?

Comment: Check the correct way to charge a Li-ion cell..

Comment: _"with a diode in series the voltage **stabilize** at 3.88V."_ - how long did you test it for, and how? Unless something is drawing a small current to maintain diode voltage drop (eg. your multimeter) the battery will _eventually_ charge to 4.5V, and then BANG!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a module like tp4056. This can charge li-ion and li-poly with an auto-cut mechanism. This is the safest way to charge a battery. You can easily get them at any store.
The thing is constant high voltage can damage your battery after some months of usage. So you have to increase the voltage in steps.